# how to show product custom taxonomies in woocommerce rest api

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'm working with woocommerce rest API v1 to build a shop page working with AJAX.

What I have tried :

- created custom taxonomies for woocommerce products post type
- set show_in_rest to true for those taxonomies
- made a request to the woocommerce rest api like `/wp-json/wc/v1/products/?consumer_key=[actual_consumer_key]&consumer_secret=[actual_consumer_secret]`

What I expected :

A list of products and their variations with categories, tags, AND custom taxonomies, for each product.

What I got :

A list of products with everything **BUT NOT my custom taxonomies**

My guess :

Taxonomies bind to wordpress post while woocommerce rest api returns JSON data like a an instance WC_Product class. But if this is the case, why do I have categories and tags ? (which are default taxonomies)

I'm pulling this data with AJAX, so `get_terms` is not an option. I can't make one request by product to get the taxonomies, I need everything packed.

Do I need to create a custom endpoint for this ?

Please let me know if I'm not clear.

cheers,

EDIT : I have just found that the wordpress REST API (not woocommerce) enables me to retrieve custom taxonomies along with products. I have several issues with this :

1. I don't have all products in there
2. there isn't any info about the product like its variations, or price
3. I don't want to make one request on both Woocommerce and Wordpress rest API to get all the data

Is the custom endpoint the only way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way using filters. I didn't know there were filters for REST API responses...
Here is my solution :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product', 'custom_products_api_data', 90, 2 );
function custom_products_api_data( $response, $post ) {

    // retrieve a custom field and add it to API response
    $response->data['custom_taxonomy1'] = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy1', [] );
    $response->data['custom_taxonomy2'] = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy2', [] );

    return $response;

}
```

`
Source : https://francescocarlucci.com/woocommerce-api-add-custom-data-default-endpoints/

Comment: I tried but it's not working